# Error when loading FastText's french pre-trained model with gensim

Tags: python, gensim, pre-trained-model, fasttext, french

I am trying to use the FastText's french pre-trained binary model (downloaded from the official [FastText's github page](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/pretrained-vectors.md)). I need the `.bin` model and not the `.vec` word-vectors so as to approximate misspelled and out-of-vocabulary words.

However when I try to load said model, using:

```
from gensim.models import FastText
model = FastText.load_fasttext_format('french_bin_model_path')
```

I get the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Supervised fastText models are not supported
```

What is surprising is that *it works just fine* when I try to load the **english** binary model.

I am running python 3.6 and gensim 3.5.0.

Any idea as of why it doesn't work with french vectors are welcome!

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem and ended up using [Facebook python wrapper](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/pythonhttp://)  for FastText instead of gensim's implementation.

```
import fastText 
model = fastText.load(path_to_french_bin)
```

Then you can get word vectors for out-of-vocabulary words like so:

`oov_vector = model.get_word_vector(oov_word)`

As for why gensim's `load_fasttext_format` works for the English model and not the French one I don't know!

Comment: That is indeed the only work around I found. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I never used FastText but the problem might be the encoding of your file. Try to change it to Utf-8 if you are macOS or to Latin-1 if you are on Windows.